# How to add timeouts in Go subtests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I'm currently running multiple tests in Parallel using Go subtests. Something like this -

```
func TestGroupedParallel(t *testing.T) {
    for _, tc := range testCases {
        tc := tc // capture range variable
        t.Run(tc.Name, func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Parallel()
            if got := foo(tc.in); got != tc.out {
                t.Errorf("got %v; want %v", got, tc.out)
            }
            ...
        })
    }
}
```

When I use the timeout flag, it kills all the tests running in parallel. Is there any way I can have timeout for each subtest? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, the timeout is a global one.

Comment: @radu-matei The question was: "Is there any way I can have timeout for each subtest?" And the answer is: No. Why is this not an answer?

Comment: Hi, @Volker and sorry for flagging this the wrong way! I removed the comment and upvoted your response. Thanks!